# Restrict the number of digits in the SQL Stored procedure Parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have an requirement to restrict the number of digits in parameter to be passed into Stored procedure. consider below stored procedure sample.

```
Create procedure Sp_test  
    @uniqueID1 varchar(100), 
    @uniqueID2 varchar(100),
    @uniqueID3 varchar(100) 
as 
Begin 
    select x,y,z 
    from  the table1 inner join table2 on a=b
    Where UniqueID in (@unitID1,@unitID2,@unitID3)
end
```

Now while I pass the parameter values, I have to check the number of digits its given,

Say `exec sp_test '123456','456789','12356'`

The number of digits will be always above 4 or 5 digits. It should not be less than 4 digits. I need to have a check of the same in stored procedure.

NOTE: Here Icould have used single parameter to pass multiple unique IDs , but I am using it in another application where this has to be passed as different parameter.

Please help me solving it.

Comment: Use a `varchar(5)`? But why are you using a `varchar` in the first place for a numerical value? Use a Numeric datatype (perhaps `smallint`).

Comment: Also, you statement seems malformed. It should be `CREATE PROC SP_test @Param1 int, @param2 int AS BEGIN`. Your `AS BEGIN` is before your parameter declarations.

Comment: @Larnu I used it might have some character as well like '1234Ab', This will be rare case

Comment: @Larnu   Using 'varchar (5)' is not helping to check if the digit is 4 or 5..!

Comment: So, what is the expected behaviour in case the length is less than 4 or 5? Basically I'd say it should be sufficient to check the length of the parameter right at the beginning of the procedure and in case the length is invalid raise an exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something as simple as using a `IF..ELSE`?

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE PROC Sample_sp @id1 varchar(5), @Id2 varchar(5) AS

    IF LEN(@id1) IN (4,5) AND LEN(@id2) IN (4,5) BEGIN

        PRINT 'Do your SP stuff here.';
        SELECT @id1, @Id2;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        RAISERROR('An ID must have a length of 4 or 5 characters.',11,1);
    END
GO

EXEC Sample_sp '12345', '6789'; --This will work, because both values are of length 4 or 5
GO
EXEC Sample_sp '12345', '678901'; --This will work, because the value would be truncated.
GO
EXEC Sample_sp '123456', '6789'; --This will work, because the value would be truncated.
GO
EXEC Sample_sp '1234', '6789'; --This will work, because both values are of length 4 or 5
GO
EXEC Sample_sp '123', '6789'; --Will fail, ID1 has a length of 3
GO

DROP PROC Sample_sp;
```

If you don't want the truncation (or at least fail if more than 5 characters are supplied), then I'd suggest increasing the value to a `varchar(6)`. It'll still cause truncation, but considering you only care if the value of 6 (or more characters), both lengths 6 and 500 fulfil that requirement; thus if a parameter with 500 characters is passed, it'll truncate to a `varchar(6)` and then still fail the check and cause the error.

Comment: Hi @LARNU, Your above solution helped me to give notification to user on the exact error , So solved 60% of problem  .Thanks .